# How to add a className to an SVG React Component

Tags: reactjs, svg, css-modules

I'm now using inline style for the SVG react component, because if I replace it with `className={s.some_class}` it does not work.

### This works

```
import React from 'react'
import s from './styles.module.css'
import { ReactComponent as Folder } from '../../assets/SVGs/folder.svg'

export default function Projects() {
   return <Folder style={{ color: 'aqua', width: '42px' }} />
}
```

### This does not work

```
import React from 'react'
import s from './styles.module.css'
import { ReactComponent as Folder } from '../../assets/SVGs/folder.svg'

export default function Projects() {
   return <Folder className={s.some_class} />
}
```

### My styles.module.css

```
.some_class {
  color: aqua;
  width: 42px;
}
```

Why doesn't `className` work for SVG component? and what's the approach here?

Comment: It works fine. Maybe you are using the wrong CSS class name. @Gass

Comment: svgs have different csc property. Try adding, `fill: 'aqua'` in your class and then see if it works.